# Move the position of figure subcaption of subfloat command

Tags: graphics, captions, subfloats

As the following code shows, it will label an 'a' and 'b' under each picture. How can I put the label at the left-top corner of each figure?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}
  \centering
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{Paris}}\quad
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{Paris}}
  \caption{Caption about here}
  \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have no right to upload pictures, so I did the following sketch map. I hope they can help to express what I mean.

what I get:

```
------------     -------------
-          -     -           -
-  fig1    -     -   fig2    -
-          -     -           -
------------     -------------
    a                 b
 Figure 1: Caption about here
```

What I want:

```
A                B
------------     -------------
-          -     -           -
-  fig1    -     -   fig2    -
-          -     -           -
------------     -------------
Figure 1: Caption about here
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[position=t,singlelinecheck=off]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}
  \centering
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{Paris}}\quad
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{Paris}}
  \caption{Caption about here}
  \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

For more information about the changes I made just take a look at the `subfig` package documentation.

Comment: I imagine this would be quite easy using (your) `subcaption` package too.

Comment: Yes, it's the same for `subcaption`, `\subfloat` just need to be replaced by `\subcaptionbox`.